# Could this query be optimized?

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization

My goal is to select record by two criterias that depend on each other and group it by other criteria.

I found solution that select record by single criteria and group it

```
SELECT *
FROM "records"
NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT "group", min("priority1") AS "priority1" 
  FROM "records" 
  GROUP BY "group") AS "grouped"
```

I think I understand concept of this searching - select properties you care about and match them in original table - but when I use this concept with two priorities I get this monster

```
SELECT *
FROM "records"
  NATURAL JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT "group", "priority1", min("priority2") AS "priority2"
      FROM "records"
      GROUP BY "group", "priority1") AS "grouped2"
    NATURAL JOIN (
      SELECT "group", min("priority1") AS "priority1"
      FROM "records"
      NATURAL JOIN (
        SELECT "group", "priority1", min("priority2") AS "priority2"
        FROM "records"
        GROUP BY "group", "priority1") AS "grouped2'"
      GROUP BY "group") AS "GroupNested") AS "grouped1"
```

All I am asking is couldn't it be written better (optimalized and looking-better)?

[JSFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5c0c8/1)

## ---- Update ----

The goal is that I want select single `id` for each `group` by `priority1` and `priority2` should be selected as first and then priority2).

Example:
When I have table `records` with `id`, `group`, `priority1` and `priority2`
with data:

```
id , group , priority1 , priority2
56 ,     1 ,         1 ,         2  
34 ,     1 ,         1 ,         3  
78 ,     1 ,         3 ,         1
```

the result should be `56,1,1,2`. For each group search first for *min* of `priority1` than search for *min* of `priority2`.

I tried combine `max` and `min` together (in one query`, but it does not find anything (I do not have this query anymore).

Comment: Please tell us the logic behind your query.  Also, include sample data and the expected output directly in your question.  Nothing wrong with the Fiddle, but your question should stand here on its own two feet.

Comment: What is the logic behind the ID for every group?

Comment: I updated question with the main goal and example data with result

Comment: The NATURAL JOIN will  scare a lot of people.

Comment: Where did `id = 56` in expected result came from it's not in the example data?

Comment: It matched the record I provided in example data, the first column (Example data are not same as in JSFiddle, sorry for that)

Comment: @joop yeah I know, I would replaced with normal join, it's only for demonstration. Hierarchy of nested queries is what scares me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXISTS()` to the rescue! (I did some renaming to avoid reserved words)

---

```
SELECT *
FROM zrecords r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM zrecords nx
    WHERE nx.zgroup = r.zgroup
    AND ( nx.priority1 < r.priority1
        OR nx.priority1 = r.priority1 AND nx.priority2 < r.priority2
        )
    );
```

---

Or, to avoid the `AND` / `OR` logic, compare the two-tuples directly:

---

```
SELECT *
FROM zrecords r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM zrecords nx
    WHERE nx.zgroup = r.zgroup
    AND (nx.priority1, nx.priority2) < (r.priority1 , r.priority2)
    );
```

Comment: Nice, I totally miss this feature!  Will try it when I get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you expect

```
 with dat as (
SELECT "group" grp
, priority1, priority2, id
, row_number() over (partition by "group" order by priority1) +
      row_number() over (partition by "group" order by priority2) as lp
FROM "records")

select dt.grp, priority1, priority2, dt.id
from dat dt
join (select min(lp) lpmin, grp from dat group by grp) dt1 on (dt1.lpmin = dt.lp and dt1.grp =dt.grp)
```

Comment: This actualy returns something else than I need. Its because of the addition but it is nice idea and can be modified by multiplying right priority by `10` (in case that there are no more than `10` priority numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `row_number()` . . . once:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by "group" order by priority1, priority2) as seqnum
      from records r
     ) r
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  I would advise you to avoid `natural join`.  You can use `using` instead (if you don't want to explicitly include equality comparisons).

Queries with `natural join` are very hard to debug, because the `join` keys are not listed.  Worse, "natural" joins do not use properly declared foreign key relationships.  They depend simply on columns that have the same name.

In tables that I design, they would never be useful anyway, because almost all tables have `createdAt` and `createdBy` columns.

Comment: Nice solution. Unfortunately I need simplier solution, its because DSL of framework I use which do not support `row_number()` function neither `over` neither `partition by`. You are right about `natural join` I forgot to mention that I will replace it, it was simplier for demonstration. Can I ask about performance over the `not exists` solution?